# different results in different OS

Tags: java, client-server

i have written a server and a client in `Java` , it works well in my own laptop which is a Windows vista business edition, but when i run it even in other version of Windows such as XP ( i didnt even change the platform) i get different results for the exact same program in the Math part of the program. what is the problem and how can be fixed in easiest way?

if i run in the Windows XP it will result as `-6.2579985891243E-310` but if in Windows vista business edition the result would be something like half of this, i am not sure exact result on the windows vista cause i have no access to it right now to run the program and get the result against it.

the result is made by running a Normal distribution library to calculate the normal density of some values and then subtracting it with some other values(all the values are in the `double`). the library im using is [this](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssjlab/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/probdist/NormalDist.html)

the architecture for both OS is 32-bit and both using jdk 1.6

Comment: how about a SSCCE? or does it require a lot of code?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx yea a lot of codes, cause to get the values it has a long way of processing

Comment: OK, but unless someone has seen and solved this same problem you're likely to get only speculation.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx yea sad but true "_"

Comment: anyway with a number that small... half of almost zero is still almost zero :^)

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx yea but still critical for me, these different small values giving me different part of a text that im analyzing.

Comment: You might want to make sure you are using exactly the same version of the Java Runtime Environment, that could make a big difference. There are numerous bugs in the floating-point libraries for Java, as it's a terribly complicated thing to implement across different platforms. I'm not an expert, but I'd first level the playing field and then try again.

Comment: @Ewald im using java version 6( jdk 1.6) for both OS , if you mean that

Comment: As @jcomeau mentioned you must show some code. Regarding JDK: same patch level and architecture (64 vs 32 bit), `java -version`? Did you try to reproduce the problem with a simple test application?

Comment: @home its 32 bit for both, jdk 1.6 for both

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this, but then again, my machines are all pretty much the same. This is interesting in the least.

Answer (score 2):

The effect is likely due to very minor differences in floating point rounding behaviour. This can be due to differences in processors, different instruction ordering optimisations by compilers, bugs in math library implementations etc.

You are unlikely to fix all the above (it's very hard even for the experts to get right!) - so I'd suggest writing your code in a way such that it doesn't depend on the exact floating point behaviour.

For example, instead of doing an equality test on floating-point numbers you should check for the two numbers being within a small range (e.g. 1*e-10)

Comment: This applies to almost all programming languages, not just Java.

Comment: @Salman - very true! though I expect people run into it more often with Java as a simple consequence of Java being deployed to so many diverse platforms